# image url relative path not working in css file

Tags: theme-development, images

When i write this in css file image will loaded

`background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/w3/wp-content/themes/test_theme/images/img.png)`

if i write this in css file image will not-loaded

`background-image: url(images/img.png)`

how i put this ( http://localhost/wordpress/w3/wp-content/themes/test_theme/ ) dynamically or any other way i can write

Comment: Where is the css file?

Comment: css file location :- test_theme/style.css

Comment: If that's true, there's no reason `images/img.png` won't work. You must have a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I a using wordpress, It  allow relative path or not? @JacobPeattie

Comment: Of course it is. WordPress doesn't do anything to your stylesheets. Once you've enqueued it on the front end it behaves exactly like any other stylesheet would.